# How would I use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in my CodeIgniter model?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter, model

I have a CodeIgniter/PHP Model and I want to insert some data into the database.

However, I have this set in my 'raw' SQL query:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate=duplicate+1
```

I am using CodeIgniter and am converting all my previous in-controller SQL queries to **ActiveRecord**. Is there any way to do this from within the ActiveRecord-based model?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: A relevant snippet with attention to secure querying practices here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252785/141885

Answer (score 57):

You can add the "ON DUPLICATE" statement without modifying any core files.

```
$sql = $this->db->insert_string('table', $data) . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate=LAST_INSERT_ID(duplicate)';
$this->db->query($sql);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

I hope it's gonna help someone.

Comment: Since this is a top result on google for "insert on duplicate key" it would be unwise not to extend this answer to cater for those who just wish that on duplicate key inserts and returns the 'id' on duplicate. =>  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate=LAST_INSERT_ID(duplicate)

Answer (score 6):

Following the snippet linked by Pickett, I made a few modifications to:

1) Update it to use the new Query Builder (CI 3), formerly known as Active Record.

2) You can now pass an associative array (key => value) or an array of associative arrays. In the second form, it performs a multi-update.

I only tested it with mysqli, and it works well.

This piece of code goes in system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

```
function _duplicate_insert($table, $values)
{
    $updatestr = array();
    $keystr    = array();
    $valstr    = array();

    foreach($values as $key => $val)
    {
        $updatestr[] = $key." = ".$val;
        $keystr[]    = $key;
        $valstr[]    = $val;
    }

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ',$keystr).") ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (".implode(', ',$valstr).") ";
    $sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".implode(', ',$updatestr);

    return $sql;
}

function _multi_duplicate_insert($table, $values)
{
    $updatestr = array();
    $keystr    = array();
    $valstr    = null;
    $entries   = array();

    $temp = array_keys($values);
    $first = $values[$temp[0]];

    foreach($first as $key => $val)
    {
        $updatestr[] = $key." = VALUES(".$key.")";
        $keystr[]    = $key;
    }

    foreach($values as $entry)
    {
        $valstr = array();
        foreach($entry as $key => $val)
        {
            $valstr[] = $val;
        }
        $entries[] = '('.implode(', ', $valstr).')';
    }

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ',$keystr).") ";

    $sql .= "VALUES ".implode(', ',$entries);
    $sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".implode(', ',$updatestr);

    return $sql;
}
```

And this goes into the /system/database/DB_query_builder.php file:

```
function on_duplicate($table = '', $set = NULL )
{
    if ( ! is_null($set))
    {
        $this->set($set);
    }

    if (count($this->qb_set) == 0)
    {
        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            return $this->display_error('db_must_use_set');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($table == '')
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->qb_from[0]))
        {
            if ($this->db_debug)
            {
                return $this->display_error('db_must_set_table');
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        $table = $this->qb_from[0];
    }

    $is_multi = false;
    foreach (array_keys($set) as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $v) {
            $is_multi = true; //is not assoc
            break;
        }
    }

    if($is_multi)
    {
        $sql = $this->_multi_duplicate_insert($this->protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $this->qb_set );
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = $this->_duplicate_insert($this->protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $this->qb_set );
    }

    $this->_reset_write();
    return $this->query($sql);
}
```

Then you can do this for a single row insert/update:

```
$this->db->on_duplicate('table', array('column1' => 'value', 'column2' => 'value'));
```

Or this for a multi insert/update:

```
$this->db->on_duplicate('table', array(
    array('column1' => 'value', 'column2' => 'value'),
    array('column1' => 'value', 'column2' => 'value')
));
```

Comment: This would be great for the [official repo](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter).

Answer (score 6):

The below process work for me in Codeigniter 3.0.6

```
public function updateOnDuplicate($table, $data ) {
    if (empty($table) || empty($data)) return false;
    $duplicate_data = array();
    foreach($data AS $key => $value) {
        $duplicate_data[] = sprintf("%s='%s'", $key, $value);
    }

    $sql = sprintf("%s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s", $this->db->insert_string($table, $data), implode(',', $duplicate_data));
    $this->db->query($sql);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: this work for me. Just copy and paste this code to model file and call from controller just like other function.

Comment: this code causes a serious security issue. you really need to sanitize `$value` and possibly `$key` as well. or change it to use bind

Answer (score 4):

You can tweak the active record function with minimal addition:

DB_driver.php add inside the class:

```
protected $OnlyReturnQuery = false;
public function onlyReturnQuery($return = true)
{
    $this->OnlyReturnQuery = $return;
}
```

find function query( ...and add at the very beginning:

```
    if ($this->OnlyReturnQuery) {
        $this->OnlyReturnQuery = false;
        return $sql;
    }
```

and finally in DB_active_rec.php add function:

```
public function insert_or_update($table='', $data=array())
{
    $this->onlyReturnQuery();
    $this->set($data);
    $insert = $this->insert($table);
    $this->onlyReturnQuery();
    $this->set($data);
    $update = $this->update($table);
    $update = preg_replace('/UPDATE.*?SET/',' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE',$update);
    return $this->query($insert.$update);
}
```

Now you can use it as:

$this->db->insert_or_update('table',array $data);

Pros: 
    uses all the active record validation
Cons:
    it is not the best (the most proper) way of extending the function, because if you are planning to update these files, you will have to redo the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the forum thread above is broken. I don't know of a better way than just using db->query for the call, if someone has a better solution, please post that.

```
$result = $this->CI->db->query(
    "INSERT INTO tablename (id, name, duplicate) VALUES (1, 'Joe', 1) ".
    "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate=duplicate+1");
```

I hope this helps someone looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a code snippet I use everytime for update on duplicates:

```
$sql = "insert into  table_name (id, name) values(".$id.",'".$name."') on duplicate key update id=".$id.",name='".$name."'";
//Executing queries
$result = $this->db->query($sql, array($id, $name));
```

Note: column `id` must be primary or unique

Answer (score 0):

Using `$this->db->query()` and parameters, this is how I do it.  the first 4 parameters are for the insert part and the last three parameters are repeated for the `on duplicate key update` part.

```
$sql = "insert into application_committee ".
       "(application_id, member1_id, member2_id, member3_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)".
       " on duplicate key update member1_id = ?, member2_id = ?, member3_id = ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array($appid, $member_1, $member_2, $member_3, 
                 $member_1, $member_2, $member_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply done** -

```
    $updt_str = '';
    foreach ($insert_array as $k => $v) {
        $updt_str = $updt_str.' '.$k.' = '.$v.',';
    }
    $updt_str = substr_replace($updt_str,";", -1);
    $this->db->query($this->db->insert_string('table_name', $insert_array).' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.$updt_str);
```