# Codeigniter's way of using using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Could you please tell me how should I use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in codeigniter's way? I have found this similar question here [How would I use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in my CodeIgniter model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3361490/1209690). But couldn't find the exact answer.

I have tried the following but its not working

```
$this->db->on_duplicate_update('id');
 $this->db->insert('voucher', $data);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look here <http://web.archive.org/web/20090221091226/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/80958/>

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `on_duplicate()` and `insert()`.
Whenever I'm parsing the file with some data and I want all duplicates rows from the new file be updated over the old rows( with no duplicates) and insert new rows - use `on_duplicate()` with unique index on table

If there is no need to update the old rows (duplicates), use `insert()` instead.