# how can i put xml files into database and after this retrieve them

Tags: xml, codeigniter

I have a problem. Is any possibility to put my xml file into a database and access them from it. I have this function that get content from a xml file:

```
function getFeed()
{
    $content = file_get_contents('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews');
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $feeds = array('title' => (string)$entry->title
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($feeds);
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->membership_model->feeds();
    }
```

And a model who insert the titles into a database and after this get the titles as a link format. But i guess is not a good idea because is not working.

```
function feeds()
{   
    $this->db->empty_table('feeds');
    $this->db->set('title',$this->session->userdata('title'));
    $this->db->insert('feeds');
    $get_feed = $this->db->get('feeds');
    foreach ($get_feed->result() as $row){
        echo "<a href='$row->title'>".$row->title."</a><br/>";
        }
```

Comment: do you want save xml content in a single field of table?

Comment: First i want to save the title, the content and if it's possible the URL's of titles or the hash?

Comment: so, you are going to save while xml file content in a column right?

Comment: yes, and after this retrieve the content from database

Comment: I'm asking that your are going to store whole file content in a table field? Or each xml tag is having columns in table?

Comment: each xml tag have a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with [insert batch](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

First prepare the array for batch insertion.

```
function getFeed()
{
    $content = file_get_contents('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews');
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $feeds[] = array(
                         'title' => (string)$entry->title,
                         'url'=> (string)$entry->url, // ad more fields if needed                        
                );

        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->membership_model->feeds($feeds);
    }
 //load view with data. No need to get same data from db again.
 $this->load->view("feed_list",array("feeds"=>$feeds));
}
```

In model:

```
function feeds($feeds_data)
{   
    $this->db->empty_table('feeds');   
    $this->db->insert_batch('feeds', $feeds_data);    
}
```

In view

```
 foreach($feeds as $f)
{
   echo "<a href='".$f["url"]."'>".$f["title"]."</a><br/>";
}
```

Comment: the url does not work. In the view when i click on one link it not redirect me on the site.

Comment: kumar_v. is there on_duplicate_key_update function for codeigniter? i want to insert only the row is not exists yet. And if the row exists i want to update it.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361490/how-would-i-use-on-duplicate-key-update-in-my-codeigniter-model